# I have a date in(string) in dd-mon-yyyy format and I want to compare this date with system date

Tags: java

I have a date in(string) in dd-mon-yyyy format and I want to compare this date  with system date.

eg.
I have 12-OCT-2010
and I want to compere this with system date in same format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`SystemDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class to parse your String, for example

```
final DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
final Date input = fmt.parse("12-OCT-2010");
if (input.before(new Date()) {
     // do something
}
```

Note that `SimpleDateFormat` is not threadsafe, so needs to be wrapped in a [`ThreadLocal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) if you have more than one thread accessing your code.

You may also be interested in [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which provides a better date API

Comment: This will compare the time elements of the date too. That is, your "input" date will effectively be at midnight, but could compare "before now" even if it refers to today.

Answer (score 2):

Use SimpleDateFormat http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String d = "12-OCT-2010";
    try {
        Date formatted = f.parse(d);
        Date sysDate = new Date();
        System.out.println(formatted);
        System.out.println(sysDate);
        if(formatted.before(sysDate)){
            System.out.println("Formatted Date is older");
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Joda Time. You can parse that String into a `LocalDate` object very simply, and then construct another `LocalDate` from the system clock. You can then compare these dates.

Answer (score 0):

Using simpledateformat -

```
    String df = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(df);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    /* system date */
    String systemdate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    /* the date you want to compare in string format */
    String yourdate = "12-Oct-2010";
    Date ydate = null;
    try {
        ydate = sdf.parse(yourdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    yourdate = sdf.format(ydate);
    System.out.println(systemdate.equals(yourdate) ? "true" : "false");
```